# Is it possible to allow a web form on a static S3 site to write data to a dynamodb table with API and Lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I apologize in advance if I am missing something obvious here. I am trying to host a proof-of-concept site on an S3 bucket (a static site basically). On the index page, I have a simple html web form that allows users to enter their first name, last name and email address to be entered on a mailing list.

What I would like to do is use API gateway to detect the post method from the form and send the information to API gateway. The API gateway receiving this post request would then kick off a lambda function that would (in my example) use boto3 to store a user's information in a dynamodb table.

I've only been able to find tutorials that send a user's info to SES so that it can be emailed to the site admin, etc.

I really don't know where else to look, or if this is even possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can try this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.JavaScript.html

Comment: the serverless framework would solve most of the infrastructure provisioning for you. highly recommend: https://serverless.com/blog/node-rest-api-with-serverless-lambda-and-dynamodb/

Comment: For a very simple use-case like this, I would try out API Gateway as a proxy for dynamodb, without using lambda as explained on https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/ To get you going fast, you can check out aws amplify on https://aws-amplify.github.io/ in addition to the serverless framework recommended in the above comment.

Comment: You can even talk to dynamodb directly from the client using the sdk for browser https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/ but you'll have less control over the access patterns to dynamodb as the client will be allowed to access it.